# why can not I use Like in stored functions?

Tags: oracle, stored-functions

I'm writting some stored functions in Oracle. One of these is a really basic function who take a string as parameter and return an another string. Here is my function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
FUNCTION get_mail_custcode (
    custcodeParam IN customer_table.custcode%TYPE)
    RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
    mail_rc   contact_table.email%TYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT   cc.email
      INTO   mail_rc
      FROM   contact_table cc, customer_table cu
     WHERE       cu.customer_id = cc.customer_id
             AND cu.custcode like custcodeParam ;

    RETURN mail_rc ;
END;
```

So it's not working.. The function seems to work well but is executed without any end.. The function is working time and time, I manually cancel the operation after 2 or 3 minutes (this query give normally instant result).
After writing the query again and again I finally (and randomly) change the `cu.custcode like custcodeParam` into a `cu.custcode = custcodeParam` and it is working!!

So my question is why? Why I can't use a `like` comparator in a stored function? Why this makes no error but the function run indefinitly.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there an index on `custcode`? What you're doing is valid, but perhaps Oracle is picking a different execution plan for the `like` version in the function (where the filter is on a bind variable) to when run standalone (where it isn't bound and it can decide the index access will be faster). But unless the tables are large I wouldn't expect to see that much difference. Really you need to trace both to see what's happening. Also, are you actually passing wilcards in the parm? If not the `like` is pointless, and if you are, are't you risking multiple matches which will lead to an ORA-02112?

Comment: @AlexPoole I'm not passing wildcards in params so I'll let the equal but I was just curious about a such difference. I looked at the the execution plan for the two versions but there is no difference. There is an index on the custcode column, he is used in both cases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cursors are all treated identically in Oracle. A query in a function will be treated exactly the same as a query you enter manually through SQL*Plus.

However, what may differ in your example is how Oracle works with variables. The following two queries are fundamentally different to the optimizer:

```
SELECT * FROM tab WHERE code LIKE 'FOO%';
```

and

```
variable v_code VARCHAR2(4)
EXEC :v_code := 'FOO%';
SELECT * FROM tab WHERE code LIKE :v_code;
```

In the first case the optimizer looks at the constant `FOO%` and can instantly tell that an index on `code` is perfectly suited to retrieve the rows rapidly via an index RANGE SCAN.

In the second case, the optimizer has to consider that `:V_CODE` is not constant. The purpose of the optimizer is to determine a plan for a query that will be shared by successive executions of the same query (because computing a plan is expensive).

The behaviour of the optimizer will depend upon your version of Oracle:

- In old Oracle versions (9i and before), the value of the variable was ignored to build the plan. In effect Oracle had to build a plan that would be efficiently, whatever value was passed to it. In your case this likely would result in a full scan because Oracle had to take the least risky option and consider that `FOO%` was as likely a value as `%FOO` (the latter can't be accessed efficiently via an index range scan).
- In 10g Oracle introduced [bind peeking](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16638/optimops.htm#PFGRF94588): now the optimizer can access the value of the variable and produce a suitable plan. The main problem is that in most cases a query can only have one plan, which means that the value of the first variable ever passed to the function will force the execution plan for all further executions. If the first value to be passed is `%FOO`, a FULL SCAN will likely be chosen.
- In 11g, Oracle has "[intelligent cursor sharing](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28279/chapter1.htm#FEATURENO07493)": a single query can share more than one plan, in the example above the value `FOO%` would use a RANGE SCAN while `%FOO` would probably use a FULL SCAN.

What version of Oracle are you using?

---

*update*

In 10g and before if this function is used often without wildcards you should rewrite it to acknowledge the optimizer behaviour:

```
BEGIN
   IF instr(custcodeParam, '%') > 0 OR instr(custcodeParam, '_') > 0 THEN
      SELECT cc.email
        INTO mail_rc
        FROM contact_table cc, customer_table cu
       WHERE cu.customer_id = cc.customer_id
         AND cu.custcode LIKE custcodeParam;
   ELSE
      SELECT cc.email
        INTO mail_rc
        FROM contact_table cc, customer_table cu
       WHERE cu.customer_id = cc.customer_id
         AND cu.custcode = custcodeParam;
   END IF;

   RETURN mail_rc;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'm using Oracle 10g so it can be the explanation. Optimizer do a full scan for suitable execution plan? Do I understand correctly?

Comment: I don't think 10g can build two distinct plans (one for wildcards `%`, one without), so I think it would be prudent to use a distinct query when your variable doesn't need the `LIKE` operator (see my updated answer).